# How to access instance variables from a threaded instance method?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I have been struggling to figure out how to access the the instance variable from an instance method running in a separate thread like in the example below. I thought the loop would be skipped after the `test.set_finished` method is called from the main thread after 5 seconds.

However my loop keeps counting and I fail to understand why. Would be nice if someone could help me out a little and tell me what I need to do differently or what I'm trying to do is not possible at all.

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__()
        self.finished = False

    def do_something(self):
        i = 0
        while not self.finished:
            i+=1
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)

    def set_finished(self, finished_arg):
        self.finished = finished_arg

    def startThreadedMethod(self):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            t1 = executor.submit(self.do_something)


test = TestClass()

test.startThreadedMethod()
time.sleep(5)
test.set_finished(True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know the answer I'm afraid, but I've voted up the question as you have given a short reproducible test case, which is always very helpful. Hopefully someone will assist.

Comment: Okay, I do see that `startThreadedMethod` is not returning - try putting a `print` statement after it in the main thread.

Comment: And putting `print` statements inside it, I see that `executor.submit` returns but the `with` block does not complete (presumably it is waiting for the thread to complete). Maybe `with` is not appropriate here?

Comment: I can get it working if instead of the `with`, I put into `__init__`, `self._executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()` and then `startThreadedMethod` just consists of `self._executor.submit(self.do_something)` - though I'm guessing that ideally you want some method you can call to join the thread at the end (even though in this simple example you are just exiting the main thread immediately).

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the help. Without the `with` block its works fine. I honestly havent looked into `with` statements so i dont really understand why but for now im happy it works :)

Comment: You're welcome. You'll see I haven't actually posted an answer, because basically I'm experimenting and don't have definitive knowledge of how `concurrent.futures` is supposed to be used. If someone else does, then maybe they can/should do so.